# Exit MFC app from a modal dialog

Tags: c++, mfc

I am on a modal dialog and on the close of the modal dialog i want to exit application.

```
ASSERT(AfxGetApp()->m_pMainWnd != NULL);
PostMessage(WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
```

But getting below exception form a member method for a private member variable of the modal:

```
Exception thrown: read access violation.
```

Is there any way to close application from ModalDialog safely?

Comment: Have you tried to debug the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ask how to post WM_CLOSE from a dialog to end your application.
and if this way to close application from ModalDialog is safely.

Yes, but you must post the WM_CLOSE to the MainWnd before closing the dialog.
The MainWnd have to handle the exit of the application.

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CAboutDlg, CDialogEx)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDOK, &CAboutDlg::OnBnClickedOk)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CAboutDlg::OnBnClickedOk()
{
    ASSERT(AfxGetApp()->m_pMainWnd != NULL);
    AfxGetApp()->m_pMainWnd->PostMessage(WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
    CDialogEx::OnOK();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to show the dialog, you would have called DoModal() from your application.

You can just exit the application after the call to DoModal();

```
dlg.DoModal();
//write code to exit application
```

You can check the return value from DoModal() and exit the application accordingly.

Comment: I like the common sense of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your CYouModal::OnDestroy() handler, call a PostMessage for main window with WM_CLOSE id. have you tried that ?